# php image resize error

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am trying to resize an uploaded image. I am getting error

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file in /home/rumdood/lib/photograph.php on line 309
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: '/home/rumdood/public_html/uploads/13018946005603.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in /home/rumdood/lib/photograph.php on line 309
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/rumdood/lib/photograph.php on line 410
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rumdood/lib/photograph.php:309) in /home/rumdood/application.php on line 22

And the image is not being resized. The last error is due to header function.

The line 309 is like this

```
$this->image['render'] = imagecreatefromjpeg( $this->s_image );
```

Line 410 is like this

```
imagecopyresampled( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'],
                     0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height,
                     $this->image['width'], $this->image['height'] );
```

And my php version is `PHP Version 5.2.6`

My GD from phpinfo

```
GD Support          enabled
GD Version          bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.1.9
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support         enabled
PNG Support         enabled
WBMP Support        enabled
XPM Support         enabled
XBM Support         enabled
```

Comment: somewhere along the line $this->s_image is not getting populated with data,is corrupted or not a jpg

Comment: @grc thats the absolute file path of image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **@charles** suggested.. both error are self explanitory

check for valid image from

```
 if($_FILES["userPicture"]["error"] == 0) {
 // File was uploaded ok, so it's ok to proceed with the filetype check.
 $uploaded_type = exif_imagetype($_FILES["userPicture"]["tmp_name"]);
 // What we have now is a number representing our file type.

 switch($uploaded_type) {
    case "1":
        $uploaded_type = "gif";
    break;
    case "2":
        $uploaded_type = "jpg";
    break;
    case "3":
        $uploaded_type = "png";
    break;
}
```

}

---

For 
`imagecreatefromjpeg()` : gd-jpeg, libjpeg: **recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG**

it was a problem with php 5 and gd2. Heres how to fix it

- php 4 : No action neccesarry it should work fine
- php 5.0 – 5.1.2 = Upgrade to the latest php 5
- php 5.1.3 – current = Declare this variable in your file before calling   `imagecreatefromjpeg()`
- ini_set(‘gd.jpeg_ignore_warning’, 1);

---

for **Cannot modify header information**  write `ob_start();` at the top of page

Reference

- [exif-imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)
- [premature end of jpeg](http://worcesterwideweb.com/2008/03/17/php-5-and-imagecreatefromjpeg-recoverable-error-premature-end-of-jpeg-file/)
- [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Answer (score 3):

The errors,

> libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

and

> ...is not a valid JPEG file

are pretty self-explanatory.  The image you are trying to work with is not being recognized by the underlying JPEG parser as valid.  It is very likely that the file is corrupt or truncated.

This is a problem with the image itself, not your code.  Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like image you are trying to load is not true JPG (probably someone have just renamed or something). Try to resave it with some image manipulation program (like GIMP). Or if you have uploaded it to the server, probably there was some error in uploading. Also if file weight more than one file size limit on server it could be brutally cutted.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rumdood/lib/photograph.php:309) in /home/rumdood/application.php on line 22
```

You have to send header at beggining of the code. there can't be even a space before `<?php` tag.

Comment: I expect the "headers already sent" error is whining about the fact that error messages were emitted and output buffering isn't being used.